# CSS: Should I use a mixin or a class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am using the boostrap CSS framework for one of my personal projects.
By default all the col- classes have a padding on both sides.
Which is good for some components.
But there are places where I don't want this extra padding.
So I usually just take a unique class (say `containerName`) being used to style that element and then-

```
.containerName {
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 //and whatever other css is required
}
```

I don't want to keep writing this **again and again**. So I decided to write a simple mixin just for that.

```
%removePadding { 
padding-right: 0; 
padding-left: 0;
}
```

and then use extend on `.containerName`

```
.containerName {
 @extend %removePadding;
 //and whatever other css is required
}
```

Is this an overkill?
Should I just add another class to those elements which has these two rules?

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use ".removePadding" as a class, once. Because in any case, you need to check which divs you want the padding, and which divs you don't. So if you just add ".removePadding" class to your div, right after your col-... class, you will have the same control, and more important than that, you won't be expanding your CSS file. And on the other hand, you can unterstand what is going on just by looking at your HTML file. Like common ".clearfix" classes.

Add this CSS rule (.removePadding class) after the bootstrap styles, to override them.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I was just trying to figure out if there was a best practice. This is one of my biggest problems with bootstrap. But it sure does make a lot of other components look good.

Comment: Yes you're right, customizing bootstrap can be painful sometimes, and oftenly you find yourself trying to find the best practices. I'm not saying that my answer is the best practice, but that what I'd do. I'd create re-usable and understandable classes like 'clearfix', as I mentioned. Hope to see more answers on this topic. I'm wondering either.